# How to solve flutter build failed with an exception

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwXmx.png)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[18.0.0].
> Required by:
> project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:18.0.0
> project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:18.0.0
> project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk:18.0.0
> > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base.

I was run flutter doctor command.Bellow this Flutter doctor summary

-PS G:\All-Learning-Project\green_dhaka> flutter doctor

D-octor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

-[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1139], locale en-US)

-[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0)

-[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)

-[√] VS Code (version 1.51.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

Answer (score 0):

Have the right dependencies and repositories on gradle file on project root:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
}
```

I think you are using `firebase analytics` upgrading `analytics`.
In pubspec.yaml add these below

```
dependencies:
firebase_analytics: "^6.2.0"
```

Comment: @Mehedi Hasan, If you like it please vote and select my answer.